# Scrape dynamic webpage with two attribute values

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I used to run the following codes to scrape a webpage.  Suddenly, the code stopped working.  I inspected the webpage and found the table row has added one more attribute. I can't figure how to fix it.  Can someone help me?

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

cookies = {
    'BotMitigationCookie_9518109003995423458': '343775001600940465b2KTzJpwY5pXpiVNIRRi97Z3ELk='
}


def main(url):
    r = requests.post(url, cookies=cookies)
    df = pd.read_html(r.content, header=0, attrs={'class': 'table_bd f_tal'})
    new = pd.concat(df, ignore_index=True)
    print(new)
    new.to_csv("tw1012.csv", index=False)


main("https://racing.hkjc.com/racing/information/english/Trackwork/TrackworkOneDayResult.aspx?OneDay=12/10/2020")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The data you see on the webpage is loaded dynamically via Ajax from different URL:

```
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd


url = 'https://racing.hkjc.com/racing/information/json/TrackworkOneDayRecords/202010121E.aspx?PageNum=1'

# sometimes the server returns error message
# so repeat until success
while True:
    try:
        data = requests.get(url).json()
        break
    except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
        continue

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

df = pd.DataFrame(data['Records'])
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                 Horse       Trainer  ...  Gear      WorkoutFilters
0          A A AGILITY          L Ho  ...                       NaN
1     A SHIN CHALLENGE        W Y So  ...     B                 NaN
2     A SHIN CHALLENGE        W Y So  ...     B                 NaN
3   A SMILE LIKE YOURS        J Size  ...                       NaN
4                ABOVE   A T Millard  ...     H                 NaN
5            ABOVE ALL   A T Millard  ...     H                 NaN
6            ABOVE ALL   A T Millard  ...     H                 NaN
7               ADONIS     D J Whyte  ...     H                 NaN
8            AEROSONIC        J Size  ...        Date=12/10/2020#b4
9            AEROSONIC        J Size  ...                       NaN
10         AFRICAN SKY      T P Yung  ...                       NaN
11            AFTER ME  D E Ferraris  ...                       NaN
12                AION     D A Hayes  ...     H                 NaN
13              ALCARI       P F Yiu  ...                       NaN
14     ALEE KING PRAWN     D A Hayes  ...     H                 NaN
15    ALL BEST FRIENDS       K L Man  ...                       NaN
16   ALL FOR ST PAUL'S       F C Lor  ...     H                 NaN
17   ALL FOR ST PAUL'S       F C Lor  ...     H                 NaN
18         ALL IN MIND      A S Cruz  ...  H/XB  Date=12/10/2020#b6
19          ALL JOYFUL      T P Yung  ...     H                 NaN
20         ALL THE WAY   A T Millard  ...     H                 NaN
21  ALL TIMES GRATEFUL       C H Yip  ...                       NaN
22         ALL TOO WIN      D J Hall  ...                       NaN
23         ALL TOO WIN      D J Hall  ...                       NaN
24        ALL YOU KNOW      R Gibson  ...     H                 NaN
25        ALL YOU WANT      R Gibson  ...     H                 NaN
26          ALLOY STAR      T P Yung  ...                       NaN
27         ALPHA HEDGE       K W Lui  ...     H                 NaN
28       ALWAYS BEAUTY     D A Hayes  ...        Date=12/10/2020#b4
29       ALWAYS BEAUTY     D A Hayes  ...                       NaN
30           AMARA WIN       P F Yiu  ...        Date=12/10/2020#b3
31           AMARA WIN       P F Yiu  ...                       NaN
32           AMAZEMENT        J Size  ...                       NaN
33     AMAZING AGILITY          L Ho  ...                       NaN
34       AMAZING BEATS  P O'Sullivan  ...                       NaN
35         AMAZING BOY     C W Chang  ...     H                 NaN
36   AMAZING CHOCOLATE   A T Millard  ...     H                 NaN
37   AMAZING CHOCOLATE   A T Millard  ...     H                 NaN
38        AMAZING KIWI     D J Whyte  ...  H/XB                 NaN
39      AMAZING KNIGHT        J Size  ...     H                 NaN
40        AMAZING LUCK  P O'Sullivan  ...                       NaN
41        AMAZING NEWS      C Fownes  ...     H                 NaN
42    AMAZING ONE PLUS      C S Shum  ...                       NaN
43    AMAZING ONE PLUS      C S Shum  ...                       NaN
44       AMAZING ROCKY      T P Yung  ...     H                 NaN
45       AMAZING ROCKY      T P Yung  ...     H                 NaN
46        AMAZING STAR      K H Ting  ...     H                 NaN
47     AMBITIOUS HEART  D E Ferraris  ...     H                 NaN
48    ANGEL OF MY EYES      C S Shum  ...     H                 NaN
49         APACHE PASS  P O'Sullivan  ...                       NaN

[50 rows x 7 columns]
```